# OpenGL blending modes (Dest Atop)

Tags: opengl, blending

How to achieve a result like DestAtop on the following picture?
[image: http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff/table.png]

In what order should I render each image and what blending functions to use? Tried literally every combination, checked every similar question, still can't get desired result.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, is not destination atop compositing effectively: `(1 - DstA) * SrcRGBA  +  SrcA * DstRGBA`?

Comment: Now, one potential problem here is that not all framebuffers store destination alpha. It is not necessary for traditional alpha blending, but if you're doing advanced compositing like this you probably already know this.

Comment: Your best option, if possible, might be to render one or both to a separate framebuffer and then run a full screen rectangle render, feeding them in as textures to a blending fragment shader. If you have other geometry, it's going to be hard to pull out the under-layer from the rest of the scene, and if you don't do that, it'll just render dest-over unless you look at the sky or such.

Comment: I suggest you look into stencil buffers, which are meant to do these kinds of things. They describe the process very naturally too, in this case.

Comment: Actually I've changed my goal a bit and choose to use depth buffer. Suits well so far. Each answer was helpful. Thank you guys.